# Selenium resize element issue

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop

I have an issue when I try to resize a element on browser. I found the right bottom cornor of the element like this:
[image]

And I try to drag the right bottom span use this function:

```
public static Actions hardAction = new Actions(driver);
public static void  drag(By by,int x,int y){
  WebElement ele = driver.findElement(by);
  hardAction.clickAndHold(ele).moveByOffset(x,y).release().build().perform();
}
```

But nothing happen when I use this function to resize. I doubt whether selenium click and hold the draggable area of span, because this function works well when I drag other element. So how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Could you share the html for the element?

Comment: did you got any error message for the particular element?